# Event.preventDefault() doesn't work on sumbit event?

Tags: jquery, symfony

I'm trying to change behavior after submit, but it doesn't work.

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on('submit', "#bissap_userbundle_role_submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  <-- LOGIC (ajax request) -->
  return false; 
});
```

HTML CODE :

```
<form name="bissap_userbundle_role" method="post" action="/bodykoncept/web/app_dev.php/admin/admin/role/2/update">
    <input name="_method" value="PUT" type="hidden">
    <div id="bissap_userbundle_role">
        <div>
            <label for="bissap_userbundle_role_role" class="required">Role</label>
            <input id="bissap_userbundle_role_role" name="bissap_userbundle_role[role]" required="required" maxlength="255" value="ROLE_ALLA" type="text">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="bissap_userbundle_role_description" class="required">Description</label>
            <input id="bissap_userbundle_role_description" name="bissap_userbundle_role[description]" required="required" maxlength="255" value="DDDDDD" type="text"></div>
        <div>
            <label for="bissap_userbundle_role_groupRole" class="required">Group role</label>
            <select id="bissap_userbundle_role_groupRole" name="bissap_userbundle_role[groupRole]">
              <option value="1" selected="selected">GROUP_ADMIN7</option>
              <option value="3">ROLE_TYPE_S</option>
              <option value="4">GROUP_ADMIN_2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" id="bissap_userbundle_role_submit" name="bissap_userbundle_role[submit]" class="update_class" data-id="2">Update</button>
        </div>
        <input id="bissap_userbundle_role__token" name="bissap_userbundle_role[_token]" value="pmIf_4lgQq8Ibi0mHfIOAISYpH1x6OQyqTOFJdfX_Ws" type="hidden"></div>
</form>
```

***Info:  I used Form from createEditForm  CRUD Symfony2!***

Comment: change your code `$(document).on('submit', "#bissap_userbundle_role_submit",function(e)` to `$(document).on('click', "#bissap_userbundle_role_submit",function(e)`

Answer (score 0):

`submit` event is attached to `form` element, not to button itself. Try like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#FORM_ID').on('submit', (function(e) { ... }
});
```

Comment: I just try this, but doesn't work for me, the form don't exist when script jquery is lauched. So I need to use `$(document).on` ! when i chek in inspector i can see the event on submit but doesn't work. Maybe, in internal - form symfony do something with this submit?!